# Bluetooth mouse that doesn't require a USB dongle

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

Since my Macbook only has two USB ports, I'd like to get myself a mouse that can pair with the Mac's built-in bluetooth. The obvious choice is the [Apple Magic Mouse](http://www.apple.com/magicmouse/), but at $70 it's pretty much overkill. I don't need the touch functionality, since the Mac's trackpad already does a great job with that.

I'm mostly looking for something that allows me accurate control, isn't too large (so I can toss it in my backpack), and isn't too expensive. And looks nice next to the Aluminum Macbook, or course. :)

Comment: Hey @Neil, how did you go on your mouse hunt?

Comment: Honestly, I've ended up swapping my Logitech mouse between my netbook and my Mac, also have gotten more comfortable with the trackpad. The Kensington I used to use is better than anything else I can find, but it's too pricey to replace just now. A better mouse trumps having that extra USB port, I think.

Comment: Why do you say you want a USB mouse to use it via Bluetooth?

Comment: Usually, we choose either a USB mouse or a Bluetooth mouse.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - That was a typo; I wanted to avoid tying up a USB port. Typo fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the [RadTech BT500](http://www.radtech.us/products/BT500.aspx) for some time and love it.  It's small, rechargeable, works well, and silver in color, to look good next to aluminum Macs.

Answer (score 3):

The Logitech [V470 Cordless Laser Mouse for Bluetooth®](https://web.archive.org/web/20110622083219/http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice/devices/3287) may suit your needs.

BTW: I've used Logitech mice for a long time now and can say that they're built very well. They're a pleasure to use. The MX1000 is the greatest mouse ever built in my opinion. I've yet to use a Bluetooth mouse though.

Comment: I've used a Logitech BT travel mouse for years now. Built well, compact size, good battery life. I don't think you could go wrong with the V470 recommended above.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP or for pricing in his area, but here in Canada, a V470 costs only $10 less than a Magic Mouse.

Answer (score -2):

Read about the Mad Catz R.A.T M. It is a mobile Gaming Mouse which doesen't require a dongle.